# How to make gradient over v-parallax image with vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, parallax

I have a simple `<v-parallax>` with some header and button tags displaying over the image. What is the best way to make gradient or just dimm the image in parallax with vuetify?
Can it be done with `<v-overlay>`?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

you might take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/behzadim/fzb76520/) and i hope this will be what you're seeking for. a simple solution might be to use `<v-overlay` inside of `<v-parallax>` and make sure to put the `absolute` attribute in order to prevent overlay scrolling with content.

```html
<v-parallax dark :src="imgSrc">
    <v-overlay value="true" absolute>
          overlay text over parallax
    </v-overlay>
</v-parallax>
```

Comment: Need to add this to the jsfiddle: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>`